# Null on updated fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update one single field in a table but it's giving me an error saying that the other content is null. I'm trying to update one single field from a table and leave the other fields as they were.

Code so far:

```
  var user = new User() { CardNumber = cardNumber };
  using (var db = new Entities())
  { 
     db.Users.Attach(user);
     db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.CardNumber).IsModified = true;
     db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
     db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: you instantiate the user and set only `CardNumber` property. So the other properties are null or default values. You should fetch the actual data and modify its properties.

Comment: In this case, how would I fetch the actual data? As I'm calling the Entity which in it there is the actual data in the class Entities

Comment: `db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userIdToBeUpdated).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @ilkerkaran `db.Users.Find(userIdToBeUpdated)`

Comment: @ilkerkaran can you specify on how to modify its properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code example to update the card number and save it.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
   User user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userIdToBeUpdated).FirstOrDefault();
   user.CardNumber = cardNumber;
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```